# Swift 3 - Use variable from ViewController inside TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables

Im fairly new to Swift and new to stack overflow.

I need to use the "id" variable set in ViewController inside tableviewcell.

**1. View Controller - Set Id variable**

```
class Profile01: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var id: AnyObject!
```

**2. TableViewCell - I need to get the "id" variable with the same value inside this TableView Cell**

```
class tableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {

parseJSON()

super.awakeFromNib()

}

func parseJSON(){

let url: URL = URL(string:"http://website/page.php")!

let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)

let bodyData = "id=\(id)&local=application"

request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue:       OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in

self.startParsing(data!)}

}
```

**id in tableviewcell is used at**

```
let bodyData = "id=\(id)&local=application"
```

Comment: Basically **do not** run code in the view (the cell) which is supposed to belong to the controller. According to the model-view-controller pattern parse the JSON in the view **controller**, populate the **model** (the data source array) and reload the table **view**. Further in Swift 3 use `URLSession` rather than deprecated `NSURLConnection` and native `URL` and `URLRequest` (without NS prefix). As a side-effect this solves your issue.

Comment: Very well asked question but I second what Sir @vadian said!